# nala search: how to find exact package name match?

Tags: nala

I need to perform package name search with `nala` and I want only exact matches, so basically, when searching for package `gimp` I want to obtain only `gimp` but not `gimp-data`.

Input:

```
apt search -n ^gimp$
```

Result:

```
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
gimp/jammy,now 2.10.30-1build1 amd64 [installed]
  GNU Image Manipulation Program
```

Input:

```
nala search -n ^gimp$
```

Result:

```
Error: ^gimp$ not found.
```

Comment: Which version of `nala` are you using?

Comment: @ArturMeinild 0.11.1~bpo22.04.1.

Comment: Ok - see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was done a lot for the search part in the recent `nala` releases.

[Version 0.12.0](https://gitlab.com/volian/nala/-/releases/v0.12.0) fixed the end-of-text RegEx search pattern:

> Search end-of-text regexp not finding matches

So if you update to this version or later, the query returns the expected results (here done for `apt`):

```
$ nala search -n ^apt$
apt 2.4.8 [Ubuntu/jammy main]
├── is installed
└── commandline package manager
```

For packages in the `universe` repository, make sure [this is enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository), to be able to find packages included here. You then get the expected result for `gimp` as well:

```
$ nala search -n ^gimp$
gimp 2.10.30-1build1 [Ubuntu/jammy universe]
└── GNU Image Manipulation Program
```

For the RegEx explained, the character `^` indicates the beginning of the line and `$` indicates the end of the line.

- The search `^something$` will return `something` only.
- The search `^something` will return all matches that *begin* with `something`
- The search `something$` will return all matches that *end* with `something`

Comment: "Latest version" is 0.12.1, looks from the changelogs like this was fixed in 0.12.0?

Comment: You're right ! 